# Why does my query return no rows with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am playing with the PDO option of PHP, and I am finding it strange it does not work. I think it is because of the binding of parameters, but I am not sure. Can anyone help me please.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $query = "SELECT * FROM occasions WHERE naam IS NOT NULL";
    
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    
    
    if (isset($_POST['merk'])) {
        $query .= " AND merk = :merk";
        
        $merk = $_POST['merk'];
        
        $stmt->bindParam(':merk', $merk);
    } 
    
    
    if($stmt->execute())
    {
        echo "query is executed";
        print_r($query);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "query is niet executed";
    }
    
    
    while($result = $stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo "<br>";
        echo $result['naam'];
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Don't think you need to close ) in `:merk)`.  Also you should only bind the same parameters as you have in the query, so if you have only 1 parameter set you should only bind that parameter.

Comment: I have corrected the code a bit. What do u think?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better way to frame your code. Try this. I believe this will work.

```
$merk = (!empty($_POST['merk']))?$_POST['merk']:null;
$brandstof = (!empty($_POST['brandstof']))?$_POST['brandstof']:null;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $query = "SELECT * FROM occassions WHERE naam IS NOT NULL";

  if($merk != null){
    $query .= " AND merk = :merk";
  }

  if($brandstof != null){
    $query .= " AND brandstof = :brandstof";
  }

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

  if($merk != null){
    $stmt-> bindValue(':merk', $merk);
  }

  if($brandstoff != null){
    $stmt-> bindValue(':brandstof', $brandstof);
  }

  $stmt-> execute();

  while($result = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo "<br>";
    echo $result['naam'];
  }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the answer... I had forgot to write the while loop logic!

Comment: if($stmt->execute())
              {
                  echo "good";
              }
                else
                {
                    echo "not good";
                }

Comment: The query didn't execute @RedStar

Comment: what error are you receiving? You need to mention the error to for me to understand and return back a solution.. just saying not working isn't going to do any good..